# Upgrading Unity container breaks interception mechanism

Tags: unity-container, aop, interceptor

We recently upgraded Microsoft's Unity in our project from version 3.5.1404 to 5.8.6. With only a few minor adjustments in our code this upgrade seemed to go pretty easy. It resolves all our registered instances without a problem. However, we also use Unity's Interception-mechanism to cache some results that a method returns in AOP-style. This cache mechanism is broken since the upgrade and we can't figure out why. Apparently, our attributes are no longer called when a decorated method is called.

It currently works as follows. We register the interception like this:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IService, Service>(some_lifetime);
container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
container.Configure<Interception>()
         .SetInterceptorFor(typeof(IService), new InterfaceInterceptor());
```

In the Service class, which implements IService we have a method that is decorated with a custom Cache attribute, like this:

```
public class Service : IService {
   [Cache(..)]
   public Result SomeMethod() {
      // Some code
   }
}
```

And lastly, our custom Cache attribute which inherits from Unity's HandlerAttribute:

```
public class CacheAttribute : HandlerAttribute
{
    // ctor

    public override ICallHandler CreateHandler(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        return new CacheCallHandler(container, and, some, more);
    }
}
```

When method *SomeMethod* used to be called with version 3.5.1404 the attribute was called first, but since 5.8.6 it no longer calls this attribute. The code however, does compile. The changes we had to make to make it compile are mostly changes in *usings*. Like `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension` which changed to `Unity.Interception.PolicyInjection.Policies`.

We can't figure out why this mechanism is no longer working. And even after extensive research on the internet, we can't find a way to get this to work. Any suggesties would therefore be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I got in your exact same situation while trying to refresh some legacy code. I got it working with:

- Changing:

  - `config.SetInterceptorFor(myType, new InterfaceInterceptor());` for
  - `config.SetInterceptorFor(myType, new TransparentProxyInterceptor());`
- Registering the class that inherits from `HandlerAttribute`

  - `Container.RegisterType<MyHandlerAttribute>(new PerRequestLifeTimeManager());`
- Register each type to intercept with special InjectionMembers:

```cs
Container.RegisterType<MyClassToBeIntercepted>(
    new Interceptor<TransparentProxyInterceptor>(),
    new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>()
);
```